# Is it possible to keep link in HTML Textarea?

Tags: html

When i place a link it displays an raw html .  like below.. is there any way to display the link in textarea?

```
 <a href="">kill</a>
```

Comment: Not using a regular textarea, but you could consider using a WYSIWYG editor (like TinyMCE; http://www.tinymce.com/)

Comment: No, but what is the problem that you are trying to solve by putting a link in a multiline text input element?

Answer (score 1):

`Textarea` is for **raw text**. If you want HTML to render then you'll have to use a rich format text editor (tinymce is very popular, as mentioned in comments).

**EDIT:**

Actually, it's also possible if you use the `contenteditable` tag on a div instead:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
</div>​
```

That way you can put your own HTML within it, but let it remain editable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rMgR3/

Comment: Just realised the link in the `div` wouldn't be clickable until you've set `contenteditable` back to `false`.